# how to get dropdown selected option text on the textbox inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

currently i am having multiple textboxes and multple dropdowns inside the `foreach` loop with same id.i have tried to get the `dropdown` selected text on change to the relevant `textbox`. currently it works only for the first text box and first dropdown. what can be the reason?

[image]

Here is my code

```
<div class="child-name-col">
    <div id="header-type" class="foodmenu-dispay-view-header headerbody clearfix">
    @foreach ($showenMenus as $key => $element)
        <div class="daily-col daily-col-200 reset-padding margin-right-20 parent-div">
        <input type="text" id="newmeal"  name="newmeal[]" value="{{ $element->food }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="mealtime"  name="mealtime[]" value="{{ $element->id }}">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-top-5 dropdown" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
             <select id="dropdown"  name="dropdown[]"  class="form-control foodrecipe_item dropdown_item" >
                 <option value="">None</option>
                  @foreach ($meal_list as  $element)
                     <option value="{{ $element->id }}">{{ $element->title }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>

           </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

 </div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdown option").filter(function () {
         return $(this).val() == $("#newmeal").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);


    $("#dropdown").on("change", function () {
         $("#newmeal").val($(this).find("option:selected").text())
    });
});
```

Comment: could you fix your indenting, please.

Comment: Try to give each input element a unique `id`.

Comment: "...multiple textboxes and multple dropdowns inside the foreach loop ***with same id***."  Each `id` must be unique.

Comment: @TimMorton it prints inside the foreach so id also same.

Comment: Exactly.  HTML disallows multiple elements having the same `id` attribute.  How is your javascript supposed to know which one it's supposed to work on.  Instead, you need to either use class, or specifically name each element with a unique name.

Comment: @TimMorton if i give a unique id then how can i use #dropdown in javascript

Comment: yeah, that's tricky.  Normally, I'd say use a class instead of an id, but you are wanting to grab a specific value.  Any of the solutions I could come up with would take some creativity... Among the ideas is to use a data attribute or use the parent `.siblings()` method. The data attribute is probably your best bet.  Use the `$key` to make the `id`s unique, then pass the `$key` to your on click function to name where the data is coming from.

Comment: I know that probably doesn't make sense... hopefully it will spark some creativity for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways you can approach this problem:

1. Use a `.class` instead of an `#id`.
2. Uniquely name each element.
3. A little of both...

*This example is off the top of my head and is intended to point you to a possible solution.  It may or may not work out-of-the-box.*

```html
<div class="child-name-col">
    <div id="header-type" class="foodmenu-dispay-view-header headerbody clearfix">
    @foreach ($showenMenus as $key => $element)
        <div class="daily-col daily-col-200 reset-padding margin-right-20 parent-div">

        <!-- Notice the unique id of these inputs -->
        <input type="text" id="newmeal-{{$key}}"  name="newmeal[]" value="{{ $element->food }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="mealtime-{{$key}}"  name="mealtime[]" value="{{ $element->id }}">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-top-5 dropdown" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">

             <!-- notice the unique id, and the data attribute -->
             <select id="dropdown-{{$key}}"  data-key="{{$key}}" name="dropdown[]"  class="form-control foodrecipe_item dropdown_item" >
                 <option value="">None</option>
                  @foreach ($meal_list as  $element)
                     <option value="{{ $element->id }}">{{ $element->title }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>

           </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

 </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // this observer will need to be changed.  Left as exercise for the reader.
    $("#dropdown option").filter(function () {
         return $(this).val() == $("#newmeal").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    // using a class to observe.  Needs to be something that isn't used elsewhere, though.
    $(".foodrecipe_item").on("change", function () {
         var key = $(this).data('key');
         $("#newmeal-"+key).val($(this).find("option:selected").text())
    });
});
```